# Magento 1 create partial invoice for specific amount and not products

Tags: paypal, magento-1.9, invoice

For a Magento order, after the order has been placed and a Payflow payment has been authorized, I want to be able to add a charge to the order. I could capture a different amount from the one authorized but this brings in the limitation issue because for Paypal amount captured can only be 15% above/below the amount authorized. In order to overcome this issue, I want to allow the user to be able to pay separately for the remaining charge. However, when the user tries to pay for the rest using the Payflow credit card again, a full invoice is created which results in the cancellation of the current order and creation of new order with order id xxx-1. 
What I want is to have multiple invoices for the same order and I believe this can be done usig partial invoices like so:

```
if($order->canInvoice()) {          
$invoiceId = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice_api')
        ->create($order->getIncrementId(), $itemsarray ,'your_comment' ,1,1);
```

}

But how do I create a partial invoice for a given price that is not related to any items?

Answer (score 0):

> how do I create a partial invoice for a given price that is not related to any items?

Specify your own new `$itemsarray` replacement, that contains a single line item that describes the charge for a given price